# Create disk image of Android internal storage without root access

Tags: android, adb

I want to do an image of the internal phone storage (the one that appears as phone on the computer if you insert the USB cable). I want to analyze the image for files to restore.
The recovery does not work with MTP so I need the image.

What is the common way to do this? Is it necessary to get root access to pull the image with adb or is there another way?

Does `adb pull /sdcard sdcard.img` work for this or doees it only transfer/copy all existing files?

Thanks and Best Regards
Matt

Comment: You can not get an image as direct access to the block device requires root (as it bypasses the file-system). In addition there is no partition that holds only internal phone storage. You can only get the content file-by file by pulling the whole directory via `adb pull`. Note that on some devices adb access may be limited on the app-external folders `/sdcard/Android/<packagename>/`. Especially on some Samsung devices adb may not view files or folder in this path.